# connect a gps tracker to azure iot Hub

Tags: azure, gps, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I bought a gps tracker tk102-2 and I wanted to connect it to azure iot hub. The tutorials I found in official documention speak about arduino and raspberry devices. My devixe can send data with gprs network.
Is it possible to connect these devices to azure hub and if yes is there tutorials about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that tk102-2 does not support HTTPS protocol.You should check the specification of the GPRS module in tk102-2. Simcom SIM800 GPRS modules supports HTTPS, but in tk102-2 the module is Siemens MC55/Siemens MC56 or Simcom 300/ Simcom 340.IoT Hub allows devices to use the following protocols for device-side communications:MQTT/MQTT over WebSockets,AMQP/AMQP over WebSockets,HTTPS, please refer to [choose a communication protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-protocols). So i don't think it is possible to connect these devices to azure hub.

Comment: Very helping, if I get a gps tracker with SIM800 module, is there tutorials to connect the device to the hub?

Comment: You can refer to this [topic](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9321863f-a08c-476a-bf6c-3f14ccc59713/connecting-to-azure-mqtt-using-sim800?forum=azureiothub) on MSDN. Or you can refer [here](https://github.com/Eclo/SIM800h-IoT-module).